# Reduce Number of Primary Keys

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, primary-key

I am working on a project which reads information from CSV files posted twice a day and stores the info into a database. Each CSV file may contain rows from previous files. Unfortunately, to get a unique row in the CSV files, you have to assign 8 columns as the primary key. I feel that this is ridiculous to work with. So, I really want to reduce the number down to one. So far, the only idea I have is to create a hash of all of the primary key columns or just append them all into one string. Before I do this, I'd like to know if there might be a better way to reduce the 8 primary keys down to one.

PK columns are defined as:

```
// ....

table.Columns.Add("plantNumber",typeof(string));    //e.g. 341
table.Columns.Add("shipLocation",typeof(string));   //e.g. 11000047
table.Columns.Add("shipDate",typeof(DateTime));     //e.g. 2017/04/18 00:00
table.Columns.Add("releaseNumber",typeof(string));  //e.g. VH6516128
table.Columns.Add("releaseDate",typeof(DateTime));  //e.g. 2017/04/14
table.Columns.Add("orderNumber",typeof(string));    //e.g. 216967
table.Columns.Add("orderLine",typeof(string));      //e.g. 0011
table.Columns.Add("sequence",typeof(string));       //e.g. 044

// ....

table.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
{
    table.Columns["plantNumber"],
    table.Columns["shipLocation"],
    table.Columns["shipDate"],
    table.Columns["releaseDate"],
    table.Columns["releaseNumber"],
    table.Columns["orderNumber"],
    table.Columns["orderLine"],
    table.Columns["sequence"],
};
```

*Note: the reason many of the seemingly numeric fields are treated as a `string` instead of an `int` is because they quoted in the CSV file, and may begin with zero's which I need to preserve. I also do not know 100% certain they won't ever contain letters.*

**UPDATE:**

I don't consider an auto-incremental number to be a good solution, because I still need to ensure that not only within the SQL DB, but within the DataTable itself that the combination of the 8 columns are unique. The individual columns by themselves are not unique. Only the combination of the columns.

Comment: What is wrong with an 8 column primary key?

Comment: What is not wrong with an 8 column primary key? ;) @Paparazzi

Comment: If the uniqueness really is determined by all 8 values, then it really should stay as a composite primary key composed of all 8 values.  There's not a good way to cut this down any and keep the integrity of your data intact.

EDIT: Yes, you can define a PK for the row itself, but you'll still need to leave existing constraints in place to ensure the data's integrity remains.  If you choose to do something like this, an auto-number (or better yet, GUID/UUID) is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

To me that is not a primary key. The primary key isn't 'the only thing unique' in your row. An unique index can do the same for you.

A primary key (in my opinion), should just be a single (often) numerical value to *technically* represent the data as unique. *Functionally* something else can define a row as unique, as you have in your sample here, but I wouldn't make that the primary key just for that reason only.

Comment: I think you're suggesting that I use an auto-increment number, which I had considered, I still need to ensure that the combination of the columns I listed are unique. In my mind, doing that is more difficult than just the 8 keys as primary.

Comment: A primary key is a special form of an unique index, so why not create another unique index for the fields that need to be unique?

Comment: "In my mind, doing that is more difficult than just the 8 keys as primary." > it won't if you consider needing the primary key as foreign key on some other table... 8 columns vs. 1...

Comment: Yes, I will very likely need the PK as foreign on another table. But, if I use an auto increment number, how am I going to ensure uniqueness of the combination of the 8 columns without comparing every single entry already recorded and coming into each other?

Comment: An unique index... (I keep repeating myself, please read into unique indexes if you don't understand what they are)

Comment: How am I going to ensure that the auto-increment ID is unique before committing it to the database? If a line in the CSV has the same 8 columns, the values in the SQL DB need to be overwritten with the new information on the other non-listed columns.

Comment: Depending on the platform you have an upsert mode. It is a combination of an insert and an update.

Comment: Or try to insert and if that fails on the index, update instead.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with a compound index. Thats's how relational databases work, but if you **really** have to you could concat or hash the 8 values that build the unique key into a single column, but that would have the adverse effect of making your data static, unless you rebuild the hash/concat index.